# warning installing npm in gitBash (npm WARN angularRegistration@2.0.0 No license field.)

Tags: git-bash, npm-install

when I try to write  **npm install** in gitbash command line I got this warning
**npm WARN angularRegistration@2.0.0 No license field.** 
how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [npm issue 4473](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4473)

> Also giving licenses (an array of objects with type and url keys) helps users whose legal departments request both the license name and the text. See this example from async:

```
  "licenses": [{
    "type": "MIT",
    "url": "https://github.com/caolan/async/raw/master/LICENSE"
  }]
```

So it depends which angularregistration you are using:

- [`alexbelyeu/angularregistration`](https://github.com/alexbelyeu/angularregistration/blob/master/package.json) does include a license,
- [`planetoftheweb/angularregistration`](https://github.com/planetoftheweb/angularregistration/blob/master/package.json) does not